# Shortcut function to populate associative array

Tags: php, function

I'm extracting data and then creating an array like:

```
$foo = $_POST[ 'foo' ];
$bar = $_POST[ 'bar' ];

$val = array( 'foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $bar );
```

Is it possible to have a shortcut function?

Something like the following:

```
$val = array( someFunction( 'foo' ), someFunction( 'bar' ) );
```

Where:

```
function someFunction( $name ) {
   return( "$name" => $_POST[ $name ] ); // Does not work!
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this function? Why can't you simply use the `$_POST` superglobal array?

Comment: The functions function is plain to see and I hate repeating myself.

Comment: I am asking what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Exactly as you see in the code above. It just doesn't work.

Comment: I fail understand what you're trying to do with the code in the question. Are you simply trying to create a new array containing the keys and values of some particular elements from the `$_POST` superglobal? Or something else? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do with the *Associative Array* definition is impossible with the current PHP syntax:

```
array( someFunction( 'foo' ), someFunction( 'bar' ) );
```

However, this is the closest thing I can think of:

```
$_POST = array( 'foo' => 'FOO', 'bar' => 'BAR' );
$var = array();
someFunction( $var, 'foo' );
someFunction( $var, 'bar' );

function someFunction( &$output, $name ) {
    $output[$name] = $_POST[$name];
}
```

Not very sexy and might be confusing also, but will do the job.

**Update**

Is it what you're looking for -- it is even closer:

```
$var = ( list($foo, $bar) = $_POST );
// OR
$var = (array) ( list($foo, $bar) = $_POST );
```

Obviously it's highly depended on the array structure, so it might not be a good idea to use it for `$_POST` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in the right direction, but not nearly big enough!

You want to define an input schema like:

```
$input = $_POST;
$input_schema = array(
    "foo" => "string",
    "bar" => "string"
);
validate_input($input, $schema);
```

From then on you can safely use `$input` in accordance with your schema.